# Python progressbar is not showing progress correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, progress-bar, ttk

I have a progressbar in Python:

```
import os
def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

import progressbar
from time import sleep
bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=file_len(os.path.basename(__file__)), \
    widgets=[progressbar.Bar('=', '[', ']'), ' ', progressbar.Percentage()])
bar.start()
for i in range(file_len(os.path.basename(__file__))):
    bar.update(i+1)
    sleep(0.1)
bar.finish()
```

The progressbar works as expected visually: it displays the progress in a bar and the percentage behind it. However, the calculation of the progressbar is incorrect.

It first shows the bar with an increasing percentage, but when the bar is 100%, the program starts to run. I have put several 'print' definitions in my code to see where the code is at that moment, but now I first see the percentage bar increasing to 100%, followed by the first 'print' in the code. After this print, the code starts its calculations.

Does someone know what I did wrong here?

Regards, Ganesh

**EDIT:**
This looks like this 
[image: this]

So the training part starts when the bar is 100%.

Comment: I guess your `print` statements are after the progress bar display code ?

Comment: Jep, so first the code of the progressbar, then the print statement.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand entirely what you want then; if the print statements run after the progressbar code, isn't the behavior you describe the expected one ?

Comment: Jep I tought so at first. So then I added the first part of the progressbar code (till bar.start()) at the beginning of my script and add the last part of the progressbar code to the end of my script. Then the progressbar showed: [                                                                        ] N/A%I: . Then I knew I did something wrong, but no idea what..

Comment: You've got to tie the progressbar updates to the real code; as it stands you're just drawing a progressbar between sleep()s, it does not represent any actual progression.

Comment: Even when I put my code in the for loop it doesn't work. I also tried this: http://gaganonthenet.com/2014/08/26/python-add-progress-bar/ , but still the same problem.

Comment: Could you post a minimal reproducible example of that ? Your issue could also be that the progressbar is written to `stderr` which is unbuffered, and your print statements are written to `stdout` which is line-buffered, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Etene, I have the code which I have here. I removed the progress bar things I tried, so that maybe you can try something.

```
import os
import numpy as np
from sklearn import cross_validation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb
import pylab as pl
from termcolor import colored
from sklearn import datasets

""" ===================================== Create New Folders ===================================== """
def create_folder(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path) 
    return path

current_dir = os.getcwd()

path_graph = create_folder(current_dir + "\\Graphs")

""" ==================================== Function Information ==================================== """

def graph_heatmap(Plot, Filename, Annot, Mask_half):

    print (colored('---- Creating Heatmap: ' + Filename, 'blue'))

    plt.gcf().clear()

    plt.subplots(figsize=(40,40))
    mask = np.zeros_like(Plot)
    mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = Mask_half
    sb.heatmap(Plot, annot=Annot, mask=mask, cmap="Blues", linewidths=0.5, linecolor='black', vmin=0, vmax=1)

    pl.savefig(path_graph + '\\' + Filename + '.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=600)
    plt.close()

""" ================================= Importing & Filtering Files ================================ """
diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()


""" ======================================== Data Mining ======================================== """
#Training
print (colored('---- Training', 'blue'))

X = diabetes.data[:, np.newaxis, 2]
y = diabetes.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state=25)
```

This one is smaller than the one I have, but the structure is the same. I want that the progress bar starts directly after importing the modulus and ends at the last line (when everything is done).